# what am i doing wrong in Pagseguro API

Tags: django

I trying to use Pagseguro API sandbox on Django but it doesnt work
I know that im passing the encryptedCard but the API cannot read it

```
        "charges": [
            {
                "reference_id": "referencia da cobranca",
                "description": "descricao da cobranca",
                "amount": {
                    "value": 500,
                    "currency": "BRL"
                },
                "payment_method": {
                    "soft_descriptor": "WEBDESIGN",
                    "type": "CREDIT_CARD",
                    "installments": 1,
                    "capture": True,
                    "card": {
                        "encrypted": request.POST['encriptedCard'],
                        "security_code": "123",
                        "holder": {
                            "name": "Jose da Silva"
                        },
                        "store": True
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    })
```

it returns
`{"error_messages":[{"code":"40002","description":"invalid_parameter","parameter_name":"charges[0].payment_method.card.encrypted"}]}`

Ive printed in terminal to see if it are be passing by post and it is but i cant figured out why the json dont reads

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while doing tests on sandbox environment. You are probably passing an invalid card number to the encryption method. Documentation suggests a valid test card number 4111111111111111.